# How to customize the submit and verification method of Django forms?

Tags: python, django

I've been making my blog project with `Django` and I was tryting to implement `Toast UI Text Editor` [README](https://ui.toast.com/tui-editor/), a kind of open source text editor which be be loaded on client web pages.

What I'm considering was **to locate the text editor inside my form**, **however**, If I do that, I have to remove the `CharField` named content(which is to be replace with the content of text editor) from `forms.py` and have to customize `sumbit` method.

But the problem is I don't know how to customize the form submit method or verification method.

**What I want to do** is use the default verification method on client side and if it tells the input is valid, then submit the form data added the content text editor.

this is my code.

p.s. I used `django-cripsy-forms`

```py
class ArticleCreationForm(forms.Form):
    do_you_wanna_get_emails = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = (
            ('option_one', "YES. I wanna get an email once someone reply to you"), 
            ('option_two', "NO. I don't need to get an email.")
        ),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect(),
        initial = 'option_two',
    )
    title = forms.CharField()
    name = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        help_text = "Here's more help text"
    )
    email = forms.CharField()
    ### I removed this field to replace this with the content of Toast UI Editor
    # content = forms.CharField(
    #     widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":3}),
    # )
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to utilize such UI text editor you cant implement them using crispy forms or the standard django forms. Try using Raw html script and use action tag to call the url in the  and don't forget the method = 'POST'. Just grab them using your views and save them.
Try to implement the Django based View class where you get to call GET and POST method and save this model form using POST method.
If you have more doubts just reply here

Comment: Actually, I got to know RichTextField in django and then I was able to apply the editor. It can be expressed like this in templates. {% form|media %}